# Unable to install VirtualBox Guest Additions for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 in Oracle virtual box but I am not able to install Guest Additions to maximize the Ubuntu screen.

I have run the following command in the Ubuntu terminal but when I click "Devices => Insert Guest Addition CD Image" I get an error that unable to insert virtual optical disk. How to fix the issue ? I need to maximize the Ubuntu screen.

```
sudo apt install build-essential dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: I have Windows 10 host machine and have installed Ubuntu 18.04 in Oracle VM. I have installed 'sudo apt install build-essential dkms' package in the terminal. I am wondering what is the next step to install Guest Addition that will maximize the screen ?